Why can I only look left to right while I use the tween

func check_if_can_wallrun(delta: float):
    var camera_tween = create_tween()
    var normal_camera_orientation = Vector3(0,0,0)
    var running_on_right_wall_camera_orientation = Vector3(0, 0, 15)
    var running_on_left_wall_camera_orientation = Vector3(0,0,-15)
    
    if not can_wall_run:
        # Reset gravity and camera properties when not wall running
        gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/3d/default_gravity")
        camera.fov = lerp(camera.fov, normal_fov, fov_transition_speed * delta)
        # Handle wall-running
    if can_wall_run:
        if wall_run_right.is_colliding() and not is_on_floor():
            gravity *= 0.5  # Reduce gravity
            camera.fov = lerp(camera.fov, wall_run_fov, fov_transition_speed * delta)
            camera_tween.tween_property(camera, "rotation_degrees", running_on_right_wall_camera_orientation, 0.3)
            if Input.is_action_just_pressed("Jump") and jumped_from_left_wall:
                jumped_from_right_wall = true
                jumped_from_left_wall = false
                velocity.y = wall_run_jump_velocity  # Standard jump velocity
                if true:        
                    camera_tween.tween_property(camera, "rotation_degrees", normal_camera_orientation, .5)

        elif wall_run_left.is_colliding() and not is_on_floor():
            camera_tween.tween_property(camera, "rotation_degrees", running_on_left_wall_camera_orientation, 0.3)
            gravity *= 0.5  # Reduce gravity
            camera.fov = lerp(camera.fov, wall_run_fov, fov_transition_speed * delta)
            if Input.is_action_just_pressed("Jump") and jumped_from_right_wall:
                jumped_from_left_wall = true
                jumped_from_right_wall = false
                velocity.y = wall_run_jump_velocity  # Standard jump velocity
    # Reset state when not wall-running
        else:
            if wall_run_left.is_colliding() or wall_run_right.is_colliding() == false:
                print("This is running all the time, I need to find a way")
                camera_tween.tween_property(camera, "rotation_degrees", normal_camera_orientation, .3)
                camera.fov = lerp(camera.fov, normal_fov, fov_transition_speed * delta)
                gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/3d/default_gravity")
                
        if is_on_floor():
            jumped_from_left_wall = true
            jumped_from_right_wall = true
            camera_tween.tween_property(camera, "rotation_degrees", normal_camera_orientation, .3)

I understand that the line:
if wall_run_left.is_colliding() or wall_run_right.is_colliding() == false:
                print("This is running all the time, I need to find a way")
                camera_tween.tween_property(camera, "rotation_degrees", normal_camera_orientation, .3)
                camera.fov = lerp(camera.fov, normal_fov, fov_transition_speed * delta)
                gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/3d/default_gravity")

Is running every second checking to see if they are not colliding. So when they aren't colliding it still uses the tween which is why you can only look left and right and not up and down.
My question is does anyone know how to fix this problem with some code. I do ask that you should be the adjusted code please. (Godot 4.)
If you need any other information the code can be found at: https://github.com/OriginallyRetro/Godot-Movement-Script
